# Decimal To Hexadecimal in Python for large numbers

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a program to convert Decimal to Hexadecimal, which is equivalent of hex() function in python. The program prints correct value till '2559'. How to get correct values of hexadecimal for larger numbers.The code fails to give correct hexadecimal representation from 2600 decimal value. Here is my code:

```
          #########################################
              #Decimal to Hexadecimal Conversion    #
          #########################################


def DectoHex(n):

    if n <= 16:
        return n

    elif n>16:          

        if n%16 == 10:
            x = 'A'
        elif n%16 == 11:
            x = 'B'
        elif n%16 == 12:
            x = 'C'
        elif n%16 == 13:
            x = 'D'
        elif n%16 == 14:
            x ='E'
        elif n%16 == 15:
            x = 'F'
        else:
            x = n%16            
        print x     
        n = n/16        
        print n

        if n == 10:
            n = 'A'
        elif n == 11:
            n = 'B'
        elif n == 12:
            n = 'C'
        elif n == 13:
            n = 'D'
        elif n == 14:
            n ='E'
        elif n == 15:
            n = 'F'

        elif n>=16:

            if n%16 == 10:
                n = str(n/16) + 'A'
            elif n%16 == 11:
                n = str(n/16) + 'B'
            elif n%16 == 12:
                n = str(n/16) + 'C'
            elif n%16 == 13:
                n = str(n/16) + 'D'
            elif n%16 == 14:
                n = str(n/16) + 'E'
            elif n%16 == 15:
                n = str(n/16) + 'F'
            else:
                n = str(n/16) + str(n%16)
            print n 
        return str(n) + str(x)


print "Would you like to continue:"
print "Enter 'Y' to continue, 'N' to quit"
Str = str (raw_input("> "))

while True:

        if Str == 'Y':
            print "Enter a decimal number:"
            dec = int (raw_input("> "))

            Hex = DectoHex(dec)

            print "The number in base 16 is:", Hex

            print "Enter 'Y' to continue, 'N' to quit"
            Str = str (raw_input("> "))

        elif Str == 'N':
            print "Good Bye!"
            break
        else:
            print "Plesae Enter 'Y' or 'N'"
            Str = str (raw_input("> "))
```

Comment: I think you can just use Python's hex() http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hex Is that what you're looking for? Or are you asking us to fix your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing any code for more than an experiment, you should use Python's hex() (docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hex). That being said, I'll help you fix your own implementation.

You're using cases to treat converting a decimal into a base 16 character, and you're doing this a finite number of times, which explains why your code works up to a limit. I would suggest defining the decimal to hexadecimal translation in a separate function like the following:

```
def toHex(n):
    if n % 16 == 10:
        x = 'A'
    elif n % 16 == 11:
        x = 'B'
    elif n % 16 == 12:
        x = 'C'
    elif n % 16 == 13:
        x = 'D'
    elif n % 16 == 14:
        x = 'E'
    elif n % 16 == 15:
        x = 'F'
    else:
        x = n % 16            
    return x
```

Notice that n % 16 could have been stored in a temporary variable.

A much shorter way of doing the same thing would be to directly grab characters from a string based on their indices:

```
DEC_TO_HEX_SINGLE_DIGIT = "0123456789ABCDEF"
def toHex(n): # 0 < n < 16
    return DEC_TO_HEX_SINGLE_DIGIT[n]
```

In your DectoHex function, you're adding hexadecimal digits on a finite number of times. You should use recursion or a loop to build your hexadecimal string. A recursion example follows:

```
def DectoHex(n):
    if n < 16:
        return toHex(n)
    mod = n % 16
    n /= 16
    return DectoHex(n) + str(toHex(mod))
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the base keyword argument to the [int](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function?

```
def decToHex(n):
    return int(n,base=16)
```

Alternatively, the [hex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex)() function will also do what you're looking for.

Comment: That function doesn't convert decimal to hex, it converts a hexadecimal string to an integer.  As well, the OP knows about `hex()` (read the first line of the question.)